# Recover password bypass

Tags: javascript, .net

in my web application, I have a password recovery functionality. If a wrong security question is provided, the server returns an error message and sets the success flag to false in the JSON response. However, if someone intercepts the response and modifies it to set the error message to null and success to true, they can bypass the security check.

tech :.net mvc

i tried this solution:
Don't do password recovery in two steps. Ask for the security question alongside the new password, and check the answer to the security question in the server immediately before the password is changed, as a part of the same request/response cycle.

problem faced: it works .but after intercepting it gives message 'password recovered' beacause we are changing response sent by server .though password does not actually changes.is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can set a token server-side and send it back along with the success response, that will send back to the server with the new password as verification. If the failure response is intercepted and changed, there won't be any token sent back to the server to be matched

Comment: In my opinion, secret questions shouldn't be used anymore. Most of the answers can be found using social networks/social engineering

Comment: but what if failure response is changed and inserted true response with token

Comment: if it's a failure, no tokens will be generated server-side